# MySQL - Query that select last row for each devices

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables on my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `speed` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `course` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `satellites` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `rt_dif` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pos_notpos` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MCC` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `MNC` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `LAC` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CELL_ID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2323 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `IMEI` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `client` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

I have devices which belong to different clients and I want to select the last `location` row of each device of a given client. Location messages may come at ANY order, could be all scrambled or the last 1000 could be from same device.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What determines last in this case: the most recent datetime, the auto_increment code, something else?  and how do these relate?  on IMEI?

Comment: How are the tables linked to each other?

Comment: The auto_increment code determines the last. The dates are given by each device and are only related to that device (only determines the last for that device). IMEI is unique for each device... The tables are not linked? Should they be?

Comment: We're trying to understand how to relate the devices to location.  Since both tables contain IMEI, I'm assuming that if we relate these two tables on that ID it would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, by the IMEI, it is unique to each device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql - need two limits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028375/mysql-need-two-limits)

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028375/mysql-need-two-limits/9032759#9032759

Answer (score 0):

This is one way... though there is faster using coorlative subquery.

```
SELECT D.*, L.*
FROM Devices D
LEFT JOIN Location L
 on D.IMEI = L.IMEI
INNER JOIN (Select max(Code) mCode, IMEI From Location group by IMEI) X  
 on D.IMEI = X.IMEI  
and D.Code = X.mCode
```

Intent:

- Return all devices and their most recent location if one exists.
- OUTER JOIN devices to location so we get all devices
- INNER JOIN to a subset of most recent locations for each device.  This join
  effectively eliminates historical locations.

My understanding is you want the "Last" as determined by the Code field in location, record for each device.  Simply put you want to know the last reported location of each device in the system; none of the history.

To get this, I assume you only care about location records for devices in the device table.  Thus the reason we start with the devices as we want them all regardless if a last location has been reported or not.

Needed to alias the max(code) as the column name wouldn't be code.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. Says `unknown table D`. By the way, in order to get the location rows, shouldn't it be `FROM location`?

Comment: `SELECT d.*, L.*
FROM devices D
LEFT JOIN location L
 on D.IMEI = L.IMEI
INNER JOIN (Select max(code), IMEI From location group by IMEI) X
 on D.IMEI = X.IMEI and X.code = D.code`

Now says `Unknown column 'X.code' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Your last edit still gives ` #1054 - Unknown column 'X.code' in 'on clause'` but I believe we're close here.