# MySQL Error #1111

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

I have a table of player performances and I want to return the high score for a each player, adding an asterisk ('*') after it if they were not out while achieving this score. This is the query I have built so far, but it gives me *Error #1111: invalid use of the group function*

```
 SELECT player_id, players.name,
 COUNT( * ) AS matches, 
 SUM( score ) AS runs,
(SELECT IF(is_out = 0, CONCAT(MAX(score),'*'), MAX(score)) FROM batting WHERE score = MAX(score) ) AS high
 FROM batting
 RIGHT JOIN players ON batting.player_id = players.p_id
 WHERE player_id <> 0
 GROUP BY player_id
```

I have looked at other times this error has come up and it supposedly indicates when a SUM function is performed over a MAX/MIN function, but I can't see where this is occurring in my query

Where am I going wrong and how would I rectify this, grma

Comment: I suspect the error relates to the subquery that selects the MAX(score) from batting

Comment: @Yottatron there's no difference if I change the `MAX(score)` to just `score` inside the IF function

Comment: When that subquery is removed it executes just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try this ie, add the column names(*player_id, players.name*) which you are selecting in your GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT player_id, players.name,
 COUNT( * ) AS matches, 
 SUM( score ) AS runs,
(SELECT IF(is_out = 0, CONCAT(MAX(score),'*'), MAX(score)) FROM batting WHERE score = MAX(score) ) AS high
 FROM batting
 RIGHT JOIN players ON batting.player_id = players.p_id
 WHERE player_id <> 0
 GROUP BY player_id, players.name, high
```

Comment: MySQL is not fussy about enforcing GROUP BY fields match non-aggregated output columns (unlike other DBMS).

Comment: @rahul still no change

Comment: That's not true @symcbean, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Yottatron: thank you - didn't know about that (and nice to get an authoritative reference) but I note that where this is enforced and a query breaches those rules it returns an error like `ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP`

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT IF(is_out = 0, CONCAT(MAX(score),'*'), MAX(score)) 
>   FROM batting WHERE score = MAX(score)

This doesn't make any sense (you can't use an aggregate function in the WHERE clause). Indeed I'm struggling to imagine what you expect it to do. MySQL is probably confused too.

Comment: I want to select the row which contains the max score, check if the is_out column on that row equates to 0 and if it does, return that maximum score alongside an asterisk, otherwise return it without an asterisk

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028375/mysql-need-two-limits/9032759#9032759